# AbstractMongoEventListener is not getting invoked

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following class

```
class MongoCascadeSaveEventListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Object> {

    @Override
    public void onBeforeConvert(final BeforeConvertEvent<Object> event) {
    }
}
```

Bean definition

```
@Bean
public MongoCascadeSaveEventListener mongoCascadeSaveEventListener() {
    return new MongoCascadeSaveEventListener();
}
```

`onBeforeConvert` is never being called.

When i check the class of `MongoTemplate`  the event publisher is set like following

```
eventPublisher = new MongoMappingEventPublisher(indexCreator);
```

The class from spring mongo package. When i see the class i dont think the implementation is correct and that explains why listener is not invoked.

```
public class MongoMappingEventPublisher implements ApplicationEventPublisher {

    private final MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator indexCreator;

    /**
     * Creates a new {@link MongoMappingEventPublisher} for the given {@link MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator}.
     * 
     * @param indexCreator must not be {@literal null}.
     */
    public MongoMappingEventPublisher(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator indexCreator) {

        Assert.notNull(indexCreator, "MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator must not be null!");
        this.indexCreator = indexCreator;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher#publishEvent(org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent)
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void publishEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof MappingContextEvent) {
            indexCreator.onApplicationEvent((MappingContextEvent<MongoPersistentEntity<?>, MongoPersistentProperty>) event);
        }
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher#publishEvent(java.lang.Object)
     */
    public void publishEvent(Object event) {}
}
```

is this a bug or am i missing something here ? Using 2.0.5.Release version of spring data mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Your config looks fine and the listener should be called, MongoTemplate implements ApplicationContextAware and hence after construction it sets eventPublisher to the applicationContext

Comment: You are wrong. Runtime value of publisher is `MongoMappingEventPublisher`

Comment: maybeEmitEvent is the method of MongoTemplate from which it publishes events to listener, try to debug it and you can see that is an instance of ApplicationContext

Comment: MongoMappingEventPublisher  is the instance

Comment: The only case when it should be MongoMappingEventPublisher is stand onle MongoTemplate outside ApplicationContext refering to spring doc in this case will only fire MappingContextEvent, hence BeforeConvertevent will not be fired